# My Samsung J5 fell and the touchscreen, as well as the LED-screen are completely broken. Hwo can I make a backup?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung, broken-screen

As the title says, the screen is completely broken. Apart from a few pixels lighting up when I turn it on. How can I make a backup without enabling USB-Debugging and unlocking the screen?

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a difficult issue. You can have the screen repaired at your expense unless its under warranty. You could try booting into recovery and using reference images and luck to do back up while you can't see it.